# Google map zooming away from desired location

Tags: css, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

So I have a pretty complex widget-box that I got from a template (I love its functionality, just having this issue), and I have placed a google map (from api V3) within it.

When I try to setZoom on a specific coordinate/marker, it consistently zooms to the south-east of the desired location.

The css for the widget is pretty complex, but the height of the widget and enclosed map are set at a fixed height within the widget.  If I set it to relative height 100%, it disappears. If I change the height, it still zooms to the wrong location

I am certainly not expecting any specific answers, but is there any specific thing I should be tinkering with in my css? I have minimal css expertise.

Is there a workaround using the google maps documentation? (I have read about the setBounds() function, would that help here at all?)

Here are my mapOptions, which I believe are irrelevant to the issue, but there may be a workaround using them:

```
var mapOptions = {
    zoom: 13,
    center: {lat:intlat, lng:intlng},

    zoomControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM,
        style: google.maps.ControlPosition.SMALLEST
    },
    panControlOptions: {
        position: google.maps.ControlPosition.LEFT_BOTTOM
    }
};
```

edit: This occurs on initiation of the map. I have passed the lat & lng positions in via a  ajax post, then this page should load and zoom on the marker.

Here is my HTML:

```
 <div class="col-md-6">
                           <div class="widget-window">
                                <div class="window" style="padding: 0px;">
                                    <div id="location-map-canvas" style="height: 300px;"></div>
                                </div>
                           </div>
</div>
```

Here is my css:

```
.widget-window {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0px;
  background: #FFF;
  border: 0px;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: #333;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
.widget-window .window {
  float: left;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 10px;
  background: #FFF;Th
  position: relative
```

cannot find the 'window' css, too many references to 'window' in the files.

This is all bootstrap by the way.

Here is the template, with their map having been replaced by my google map: http://wrapbootstrap.com/preview/WB0M6G7G4

Sincere thanks for any help, it would be absolutely great to figure this out.

Comment: Please at least provide the code for one of your markers, click listener and zoom functions. And your CSS as well.  http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Hey, I will add the css in a second here (its really complex-multilayered) and will write a snippet about the page. It is on initiation of the map, not attached to a click function